# Angular Material SpeedDial starts open on Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

Browsing through the ngMaterial issues I can spot a few mentions on SpeedDial, namely [here](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/6788), [here](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/6789), and [here](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/6111).

What I am noticing though is that by adding `ng-cloack` I can get rid of the "starting as open" issue on Chrome, but it still remains on Firefox. There is no mention of this Firefox specific issue anywhere though.

Has anyone encountered this before and if yes is there a workaround?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this yet? I was just about to ask the same question.

Comment: @muninn9 no I have not been able to solve this until now, I will post the solution if I manage to find one.